# What's the difference between Architectural Patterns and Architectural Styles?

Tags: architecture, architectural-patterns

In *Software Architecture - Foundations, Theory and Practice*, I can find definitions for both. The problem is that I don't get what each one of them means in plain English:

#### Architectural Pattern

> An Architectural Pattern is a named collection of architectural design decisions that are applicable to a recurring design problem parameterized to account for different software development contexts in which that problem appears.

#### Architectural Style

> An Architectural Style is a named collection of architectural design decisions that (1) are applicable in a given development context, (2) constrain architectural design decisions that are specific to a particular system within that context, and (3) elicit beneficial qualities in each resulting system.

What does each one mean and what are the differences between them?

Comment: This question should be migrated to softwareengineering site

Answer (score 67, accepted):

An Architectural Pattern is a way of solving a recurring architectural problem. MVC, for instance, solves the problem of separating the UI from the model. Sensor-Controller-Actuator, is a pattern that will help you with the problem of actuating in face of several input senses.

An Architectural Style, on the other hand, is just a name given to a recurrent architectural design. Contrary to a pattern, it doesn't exist to "solve" a problem.

Pipe&filter doesn't solve any specific problem, it's just a way of organizing your code. Client/server, Main program & subroutine and Abstract Data Types / OO, the same.

Also, a single architecture can contain several architectural styles, and each architectural style can make use of several architectural patterns.

Comment: What is meant by recurrent architectural design? Give some example

Answer (score 18):

**Architectural Style**  style refers to a set of guidelines or principles for designing and building software systems.

| Category | Architecture styles |
| --- | --- |
| Communication | SOA, ROA, Message Bus |
| Deployment | Client/Server |
| Domain | Domain Driven Design,Monolithic, Mocroservice |
| Structure | Component-Based, Object-Oriented, Layered, Plug-ins |
| Other | REST, Peer-to-peer, Cloud computing, Internet of Things, Blockchain... |

**An Architectural Pattern** is a specific, reusable solution to a common problem or design issue in software architecture.

- For example: 3-tier, N-tier, MVC, Model View ViewModel, Publish-subscribe,Sensor-controller-actuator...

An architectural style is a blueprint of the system's overall structure, while an architectural pattern is a blueprint of a specific part of the system

**A Design pattern** is a general reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem in object-oriented software design. It provide a blueprint for how to solve a specific problem or design issue at the level of individual classes and objects, rather than the overall structure of a system.

- For example: Factory, Singleton, Prototype.

**Real-life example:** Temple architecture styles would be same but inner design could be different:

[image]

Comment: is REST really an architectural pattern? Or a communication mechanism?

Comment: This answer is just mixing up a lot of things. I think I saw the same info on some Wikipedia page. Categories make no sense because all mentioned styles belong to all of them. Message bus, Rest are just parts of the pattern.

Answer (score 15):

Frankly, I have always considered both these terms to be synonymous! And layman (relatively speaking) literature definitely treats them as such.
Refer [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658117.aspx) or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_architecture)

However, your question intrigued me a bit so I did a bit more digging and frankly...I couldn't find much except for a reference to [A Practical Guide to Enterprise Architecture (The Coad Series)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131412752), from which i quote:

> An *architectural style* (Base et al. 1997) and an *architectural pattern* (Buschmann et al. 1996) are essentially synonymous.

Based on some more [googling](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:qgQRZ7yRUhYJ:shapingsoftware.com/2008/08/10/architectural-styles-patterns-and-metaphors/+architectural+patterns+versus+style&cd=9&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=sg), this is what I think might be one possible way to differentiate the two:

- An *architectural style* is a conceptual way of how the system will be created / will work.
- An *architectural pattern* describes a solution for implementing a style at the level of subsystems or modules and their relationships.

How an *architectural pattern* will differ from a *Design pattern* i.e. Adapter, observer is basically by the level of Granularity at which they are applied (I know this isn't part of the question but it's related, I think...)

Comment: +1 - I think you're right.  Patterns are quite well defined where-as Architectural Styles seem a bit more vague and maybe a bit higher-level.

Comment: If you're interested, I made a new answer to this topic with what i've learnt on a Software Design course this semester.

Answer (score 7):

In very simple words:

- **[An architectural style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_style)**

  Is a concept, theory (and how it's implemented it is up to you). It can also apply to outside of the software world.

  In example: REST ([Representational State Transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)) is an **architectural style** built on certain principles using the current “Web” fundamentals.
- **[An architectural patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_pattern)**

  Describes a solution at the software system (or module) level. In other words how it interacts each other e.g. view with model, and model with controller.
- **[A design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern)**

  Is a solution at the core level, it talks about classes, functions and how actually the logic flows.

Answer (score 3):

In my view, patterns and architectural styles are complementary mechanisms for encapsulating design expertise.  An architectural style provides a collection of building block design elements, rules and constraints for composing the building blocks, and tools for analyzing and manipulating designs created in the style. 
Styles generally provide guidance and analysis for building a broad class of architectures in a speciﬁc domain whereas patterns focus on solving smaller, more speciﬁc problems within a given style (or perhaps multiple styles).

Answer (score 3):

### Architectural Styles

Architectural styles are names which represent the broader organizations of your applications subsystems and depict the idea of the overall outline of the it. Examples are, `SOA`, `Client/Server`, `Message Bus` etc.

### Architectural Patterns

Architectural patterns are names of the reusable solutions to the general architectural problems which give an idea of how the inner parts are implemented to solve them. Examples are, `2-Tier`, `3-Tier`, `N-Tier`, `MVC`, `REST` etc.

One style can use multiple patterns to solve multiple problems. For example, a **Client/Server style** can use an **N-Tier pattern** or(and) an **MVC pattern** for separating its *business logic*, *presentation logic* and *data logic* for introducing modularity which solves `modifiability` and `maintainability` problems.

Answer (score 2):

Architectural design patterns are more domain specific where are architectural styles are more generic and usable in wide range of applications. Because of this architectural patterns requires more domain knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

For Architectural Patterns think specific ways to style your code as described by the [GoF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) like; Adapter, Strategy, Builder, Mediator, etc

For Architectural Style think overall system; I.E., using MVC for presentation, DDD to model the business layer, WCF (if you're into .NET) for Interop, SOA for integration, etc.

Comment: Actually, I think you are totally off on this. I'll post a detail answer in some minutes.

Comment: Adapter, Strategy, Builder, Mediator are Design Patterns and not Architectural Patterns. Different thing, those are for the more fine grained "how" decisions that Software Architecture doesn't deal with but Software Design does.

Answer (score 0):

Architectural Patterns – define a general set of element types and their
interactions. Examples of Architectural Patterns include Pipes and Filters,
Model–View–Controller, and Reflection.

Architectural Style – the term was coined by Garlan and Shaw, it is an
idiomatic pattern of system organization. For example, a client–server system
is an architectural style.

p.s : Many of the original architectural styles have been
reformulated as patterns.

Comment: So you are saying that Pipes and Filters are now patterns? Because in the Software Architecture book I'm reading, explicitly lists Pipes and Filters as a style.

Answer (score 0):

Architecture style describes a system of many components. There is only one application architecture and you have to apply the one architectural style like Microservices, SOA, and event-driven architecture everywhere.

Architecture patterns describe something inside a single component and do not try to apply the same architectural patterns like CQRS or DDD everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Architectural styles tell us, in very broad strokes, how to organize our code. It’s the highest level of granularity and it specifies layers, high-level modules of the application and how those modules and layers interact with each other, the relations between them. Examples of Architectural Styles: Component-based, SOA

Architectural Patterns have an extensive impact on the code base, most often impacting the whole application either horizontally (ie. how to structure the code inside a layer) or vertically (ie. how a request is processed from the outer layers into the inner layers and back). Examples of Architectural Patterns: Model-View-Controller, Model-View-ViewModel

Answer (score -1):

**Architecture pattern:** context + problem -> solution

**Architecture style:** solution part of architecture pattern

So architecture style is analogous to the solution part of the architecture pattern. It's often used in books dealing with architecture documentation where the focus is on the solution and not how the context and problem came about.